# Python Selenium - Next line delimited issue

Tags: python, selenium

This is HTML:

```
<h1>
        Sample Test
    </h1>
```

I need to use `=` to find the text on the page.

What will be the easiest way to fix this XPATH, so it will work:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h1[text()="Sample Test"]')
```

Please do not suggest to use `/n` as part of the "Sample Test" string

Comment: Perhaps `contains()` if the right function for your xPath: `//h1[contains(text(), "Sample Test")]`

Comment: @pavelsaman I need to make it work with `=` and if I will use contains it will pick up different elements on the page and this is causing issues in the long run

Comment: What is the *exact* string to match? "Sample Test" or "*<leading whitespace.....>*Sample Test"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` using `normalize-space()`

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[normalize-space(text())="Sample Test"]')
```

OR

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[normalize-space(.)="Sample Test"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [contains()](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#6) method if you don't want to match the whole field.

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h1[contains(text(),"Sample Test"]')
```

Comment: Yes, but (sorry I know this is not clear), I need to make it work WITH  `=`